# Python bash script

Tags: python, shell

I need help regarding bash scripting as I am new to it.

In the pycharm project I have a file .env.development

It has all the required valriables like-

A=aa ,B=bb ,Python_env=python

Now I need to read this Python_env from the .env.development file (output = python). And I need to use this 'python' in a different file.

The logic which I could think is to create a new .py file and read the .env.development (Python_env) file and output of that file I could use in my master script file.

Please guide me how to do that?

Example:
Consider 3 files-
1)Master.sh 2).env.development 3)Read_env.py

In Read.env file I need a bash script to read Python_Env from .env.development.

After reading the environment I need to use that file in master.sh.
Master.sh has code like --
(Python -m uvicorn)

So python needs to be replaced by some command which is reading the environment variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "bash scripting in python"? `bash` and `python` are two different scripting languages.

Comment: I have added more clarity in question, i need bash script to read a variable from one file and use it in other.